# How can access random .csv file on my computer for further manipulations?

Tags: python, csv

I am only at the beginning of my python programming way.

```
f = csv.reader(open('andr.csv'), delimiter=',') 
andr=[] 
for row in f:
```

This is for specific .csv file in my comp. I want to INPUT random file

```
file=print(input('File to analyze: ')) 
f = csv.reader(open(file), delimiter=',') 
andr=[] 
for row in f:
```

This obviously doesn't work. As I've already told, I am just starting to study python and it is probably very easy, but I am stuck here. I appreciate any help.

Comment: You seem to be jumping into the deep end when many tutorials exist in the shallow end. Its best to run through a few of those first.

Answer (score 0):

This is how basic prompts and csv reader work

```
import csv

while True:
    filename = input('File to analyze: ')
    try:
    with open(filename, endline='') as fp:
        for row in csv.reader(fp):
            print(row)
        break
    except Exception as e:
        print("Invalid file {} ({}), try again.".format(filename, e))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob` module to get any filenames with specific extension(.csv) from any directory.

Then by using `Random` module you can randomly select any one file,

Please try this code,

```
import random
import glob

#total_files contains all CSV file names.
total_files = glob.glob(('*.csv'))

#randomly selecting one csv file.
file = random.choice(filee)

f = csv.reader(open(file), delimiter=',') 
andr=[] 
for row in f:
```

Please let me know in terms of any queries.

Comment: Thank you. The point is, that I have to access the file in my directory. Thats why I used 'filename = input('File to analyze: ')'. Where can it be inserted in your code?

Comment: this will look for files in current directory were script is placed, if you want to specify certain directory then use 'dir_name/*.csv' instead of '*.csv'

Comment: Example : total_files = glob.glob(('D:\Backup\New folder\elasticSearch\scripts\*.jl'))